# Far Manager does not show new tab (PanelTabs)

Tags: far

Windows 10 (64 bit), Far Manager 3  v3.0 build 5254 x64

I download plugin **PanelTabs** (ver. 1.15.0.0) [from official site](https://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?l=ru&pid=873).

Unpack archive and copy to `%Far%/Pluggins` folder.
Restart Far. Press <kbd>F11</kbd>. 
Add current folder to tab by select "`Add Tab`"

[image]

But new tab is not shown:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

> The plugin adds a row of bookmarks to the FAR panels, which can be switched by mouse or keyboard. To make the tabs visible you should **reduce the height of the panels by at least one line (Ctrl + Up)**

### Documentation

You can see the help (in Russian), by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>, go to `Panel tabs` and press <kbd>F1</kbd>. I've translated the documentation here: https://superuser.com/a/1280376/274351 (with the help of Google Translate).

### Example

[image]

### Alternative

I usually set shortcuts to different folders and then jump to them.

- Create a folder shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
- Jump to a folder shortcut               <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>